# se faire + infinitive vs être + participe passé

Tags: sens

I have read the following in https://fr.quora.com/Si-je-me-fais-arr%C3%AAter-pour-exc%C3%A8s-de-vitesse-et-que-le-policier-demande-Vous-savez-pourquoi-je-vous-arr%C3%AAte-devrais-je-r%C3%A9pondre-Oui-j-allais-%C3%A0-65-au-lieu-de-50-ou-ne-rien-dire-du-tout :

> Si je me fais arrêter pour excès de vitesse...

Is there any difference in meaning between that and

> Si je suis arrêté pour excès de vitesse...

?

**Literally**, "se faire qqch" implies that the person wants the action to happen and it's doing something to cause it, but nobody wants to be stopped by the police. Does the expression have a non-literal meaning in French?

Comment: In this context "se faire" definitely does not necessarily mean causing or wanting to cause the action. That's because "se" does not have to be active. It can be used in a passive sense. For example, "Un bruit s'entend" just means that a noise is heard (by someone else). "Un bruit se fait entendre" follows the same logic. And similarly for a person who, directly or indirectly, gets stopped.

Comment: Is there any diff in meaning when a reflexive pronoun (e.g. me, te, se) is used for expressing passive voice and when it's not (in this case, "si je me fais arrêter" vs "si je suis arrêté") ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no significant difference in meaning with the speeding context. ***Si je suis arrêté** pour excès de vitesse [...]* is just less common and slightly less clear.

Without context:

- ***Je suis arrêté*** just means I do not move (I'm stopped) but might also mean I'm on sick leave.
- ***Je me fais arrêter*** means someone enforcing the law stops me (I'm being arrested/I'm arrested).

In the Quora sentence ***Je me fais*** doesn't imply any willingness.

To express it, you would say:

> *Si **je me fais arrêter volontairement/délibérément** pour excès de vitesse* (more formal)
> or
> *Si **je fais exprès de me faire arrêter** pour excès de vitesse* (usual).

Comment: "Si je suis arrêté" is less clear if used by itself, right? In the context of the text linked in the question, "si je suis arrêté por excès de vitesse et que le policier demande, « Vous savez pourquoi je vous arrête ? »", it is clear that the person was **forced to stop by the police**.

Comment: -- That's right.

Comment: and if you say *Je me suis fait arrêter par mon médecin*, it is clear your doctor didn't handcuff you :-)